# I seem to be using only some part of my total memory

Tags: linux, memory

My Kubuntu laptop

```
 $ uname -a
   Linux jiggs 3.16.0-31-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 17:37:36 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

has 6GiB of memory:

```
  # lshw -C memory
   *-firmware              
   description: BIOS
   vendor: TOSHIBA
   physical id: 0
   version: Version 6.50
   date: 11/26/2012
   size: 128KiB
   capacity: 8128KiB
   capabilities: isa pci pnp upgrade shadowing vesa cdboot bootselect edd int13floppytoshiba int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot
  *-memory
   description: System Memory
   physical id: 1f
   slot: System board or motherboard
   size: 6GiB
  *-bank:0
      description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
      product: HMT351S6CFR8C-PB
      vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
      physical id: 0
      serial: 3F720214
      slot: DIMM0
      size: 4GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
   *-bank:1
      description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
      product: HMT325S6CFR8C-PB
      vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
      physical id: 1
      serial: 046584F8
      slot: DIMM2
      size: 2GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
```

from which I deduce I have (as my recollection of the specs at the time of buying serves me) 6GiBs.

However, other instruments report otherwise:

```
  $ vmstat -s
  4942348 K total memory
  3043944 K used memory
  1591504 K active memory
  1160736 K inactive memory
  1898404 K free memory
    93484 K buffer memory
   810816 K swap cache
  4194300 K total swap
   242832 K used swap
  3951468 K free swap
  7151425 non-nice user cpu ticks
    22453 nice user cpu ticks
   401211 system cpu ticks
 94036935 idle cpu ticks
    62616 IO-wait cpu ticks
      246 IRQ cpu ticks
     3030 softirq cpu ticks
        0 stolen cpu ticks
  1570974 pages paged in
  9494712 pages paged out
     1695 pages swapped in
    18084 pages swapped out
 87647428 interrupts
199120848 CPU context switches
1426162570 boot time
    41765 forks
```

or

```
 $ free -h
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4,7G       2,9G       1,8G       209M        91M       796M
-/+ buffers/cache:       2,0G       2,7G
Swap:         4,0G       237M       3,8G
```

or, lastly,

```
 $ cat /proc/meminfo 
 MemTotal:        4942348 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 MemFree:         1892556 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 MemAvailable:    2483472 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Buffers:           93844 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Cached:           815388 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 SwapCached:       180524 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Active:          1595312 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Inactive:        1162484 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Active(anon):    1128632 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Inactive(anon):   934308 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Active(file):     466680 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Inactive(file):   228176 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Unevictable:          68 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Mlocked:              68 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 SwapTotal:       4194300 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 SwapFree:        3951468 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Dirty:                 0 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Writeback:             0 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 AnonPages:       1671124 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Mapped:           296016 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Shmem:            214376 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Slab:             167272 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 SReclaimable:     130004 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 SUnreclaim:        37268 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 KernelStack:        9552 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 PageTables:        56688 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 NFS_Unstable:          0 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Bounce:                0 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 WritebackTmp:          0 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 CommitLimit:     6665472 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Committed_AS:    6178500 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 VmallocUsed:      354304 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 VmallocChunk:   34359375180 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 AnonHugePages:    638976 kB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 HugePages_Total:       0
 HugePages_Free:        0
 HugePages_Rsvd:        0
 HugePages_Surp:        0
 Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
 DirectMap4k:       75328 kB
 DirectMap2M:     5027840 kB
```

This last output is possibly important because it does **not** report any hardware problem: *HardwareCorrupted = 0 kB*. Whence the discrepancy?

EDIT: @Sobrique rightly points out I should have included the BIOS info:

```
  Total Memory Size   6140MB
```

Edit2:

```
 # dmesg | grep Memory
 [    0.000000] Memory: 5957056K/6166700K available (7384K kernel code, 1145K rwdata, 3408K rodata, 1336K init, 1444K bss, 209644K reserved)
 [    1.201086] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange thing is, after a reboot the discrepancy is no longer there:

```
 $ dmesg | grep Memory
 [    0.000000] Memory: 5957056K/6166700K available (7384K kernel code, 1145K rwdata, 3408K rodata, 1336K init, 1444K bss, 209644K reserved)
 [    1.312970] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
 $ free -h
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          5.7G       3.8G       1.9G       334M       274M       1.6G
-/+ buffers/cache:       1.9G       3.8G
Swap:         6.0G         0B       6.0G
  $ vmstat -s | head -1
  5987640 K total memory
  $ head -1 /proc/meminfo
  MemTotal:        5987640 kB
```

I am relieved of course, yet intrigued: I have no idea as to what may  cause a temporary decrease in the available memory.

Comment: `[drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M` might a a clue—maybe it's been given to the graphics hardware?

Comment: @derobert The same amount is allocated to the graphics hardware when the total tallies, and when it doesn't, so it seems unlikely, to me, that it may make a difference.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae For Intel graphics cards, the 2048M is the *max* shared memory amount that can be given to the GPU; it varies dynamically ­– see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/475405/107321). Not sure if this memory would be included in `free`'s total, but if not, it could explain your issue.

Answer (score 0):

4G is a special number, because it's 2^32. This is quite a good indicator as to where the root cause might be. It's not uncommon to run into 32 and 31bit memory limits. You've gone past this - you're on 4.7G - so it's not a problem with your 32bit-ness.

With a bit of digging, suggests it's not uncommon to reserve system RAM for your graphics card.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/82917/ubuntu-detects-only-3-2gb-ram-on-a-64bit-os

Either that or it's BIOS related:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/80721/only-3-2-gb-of-memory-being-used-on-a-64-bit-system
http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=297556

Comment: Regretfully (for me!), my BIOS recognizes the full amount of memory present, and the total memory assigned to the graphics card is a mere 256MB